# Thymeleaf fails to load resources

Tags: html, thymeleaf

Hello i'm trying to render my html page with thymeleaf but it fails to load the .js file. I'm using spring-boot and my file structure is `src/main/resources/templates` this contains all my html files. My css files are located in `src/main/resources/static/css/`. My .js files are located in `src/main/resources/js/`.

Now i tried rendering my guest.html file but it's failing to load resources as i tried inspecting the element on chrome and it displays error message below:

```
http://localhost:8080/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/js/bootstrap.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Below is the issue in my guest.html file that fails to locate the resources:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" th:src="@{https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js}" ></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js" th:src="@{js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js" th:src="@{js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js}"></script>
```

Comment: On a sidenote, when using the `@{...}` link url expressions, you should always start your resource urls with a `/`. This makes sure Thymeleaf will create a link starting from the context path.

Answer (score 7):

Spring Boot does not serve static content from `src/main/resources` by default. It serves content from the following **classpath** locations:

- `classpath:/META-INF/resources`
- `classpath:/static`
- `classpath:/resources`
- `classpath:/public`

Therefor, `src/main/resources/static/css` is served, but not `src/main/resources/js/`.

Move the `js` directory to the `src/main/resources/static` directory to have it served. Another option is to add a resource handler:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/js/");
}
```

You can also override the `spring.resources.staticLocations` property.

More information about serving static content with Spring Boot can be found in the [Spring Boot Documentation: Static Content](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).